# I don't understand: stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x400)?

Tags: c, debugging, exc-bad-access

The error is pointing to a line that has nothing in it. I thought I was making the 
linked list incorrectly, but I am unsure what is going on. Could the file just be corrupt or does this deal with memory allocation and memory pointers, since I am unsure how reliable my doubly linked list method is even working. Thanks for the help. 
'

```
        #define EXTERN
        #include "header.h"
        #include <stdlib.h>
        #include <stdio.h>
        #include <math.h>
        int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

            int N; 
            //int oddsonly = (BITS_PER_SEG*2) - 1; 
            int NSegs;
            int numOfPrimes;

            if (argc == 2) sscanf(argv[1],"%d",&N);
                else scanf("%d",&N);
                NSegs = (int)ceil(  ((N-3 )/(float)odds_only)  );
                printf("This is the number of segments made: %d\n", NSegs);
            //this is how we make a doubly linked list 
            //void makelinkedlist(){
            //this is how we make a doubly linked list 
            //void makelinkedlist(){
            int i; 
            seg *node; 
            seg *current;
            //head = (seg*)malloc(sizeof(seg));
            head = NULL;
            for(i = 0; i <= NSegs; i++ ) { 
                if(i == 0) {
                    node = malloc(sizeof(seg)); 
                    node->prev = NULL; 
                    node->next = NULL;
                    head = node;
                }//if
                else{
                    //current = malloc(sizeof(seg)); 
                    current = head; 

                    while(current->next != NULL){
            current = current->next; 
        }
                    }//while
                    current->next = malloc(sizeof(seg)); 
                    node = current->next; 
                    node->prev = current; 
                    node->next = NULL; 
                    //head = head;   
                    }//else
                }//for


           printf("Done allocating %d nodes\n",i);  


           sieveOfE( N );    // Modify my solution in C project 1 !!!

           numOfPrimes = countPrimes( N );

           printf("Number of primes found = %d\n", numOfPrimes );

         //  if ( numOfPrimes <= 3000 ) 
           //   printPrimes( N );

           // void decompostion(int N){
           //   int sums; 
           //   int L = 3;
           //   int R = N-L; 
           //   int keepL;
           //   int keepR; 
           //   while(L <= (N/2)){
           //       if(!testIsBit0(L) & !testIsBit0(R)){
           //           keepL = L;
           //           keepR = R;
           //           sums++;
           //       }
           //       L= L+2; 
           //       R = R-2; 
           //   }
           //   printf("%d = %d + %d out of %d solutions \n",N, keepL, keepR, count );
           // }


           printf("Done.\n");
        }
```

and I am receiving this: 
[image]

[image]

Comment: `for(j = 0; j < i; j++) { current=current->next;}`. That looks wrong. For example, when `i==1` it will execute the body once. But there is only one node at that point so `current->next` is `NULL`. So after executing the for loop, `current` will be `NULL`. In fact, `current` will always be `NULL` at the end of that for loop.

Comment: I previously had this: while(current->next != NULL){
    current = current->next; 
   }, but i thought the new way was better, nevertheless i still receive the same error

Comment: i just switched it to the previous form

Comment: RE incorrect code line, perhaps you have a mismatch between the code and the binary. Can happen if you change the code but don' rebuild (can't say whether that is the case for you since you haven't said what your dev env is and what your debugger is). And now with your update, the code and the screen shot no longer match. Please correct. Attention to detail is important if you want accurate help.

Comment: I apologize, but what is dev env? I am just using the debugger in the terminal from my Mac so I used lldb. I just provided the new picture, which I should have done since i did change the code. Sorry about that and thanks for the heads up.

Comment: devenv = development environment (abbreviation). What he means is you should just recompile everything and try again.

Comment: I meant development environment. If you are using an IDE then it ensures you are always debugging the latest code. If you are building and debugging seperately then it's possible for the code and binary to be out of sync. And BTW, a doubly linked list by definition should never have a `NULL` next or prev pointer in any of the nodes.